# Swapping mouse buttons for select applications under Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, autohotkey, copy-paste, mouse-click

I am in need of a solution to swap the Middle and Right mouse buttons on Mac OSX.

The middle mouse button in X-window and Mac Terminal is used for pasting. But it is too hard to click on my mouse (it is a scroll wheel button)

I want to use the right click to Paste within Terminal and VNC Viewer. I only want the swapping to happen for select applications. Is there a way to do it? I have looked into multiple ways including IronAHK, Mouse Key (Accessibility) but haven't come cross a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option would be to use a tool such as [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net/). This allows you to change next to all input devices and change their functionality.

Aside from 3rd party software, I do not believe there is a build in way to change your Mouse Pointer Options built into OS X (minus from what is available in System Preferences -> Mouse.

I haven't personally used [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net/), instead I have used [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/). My only gripe with MaigicPrefs is that it hasn't really been updated past 10.7 so there are a few glitches and some non-working functionality.

I suggest giving ether of these tools a try to see if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I checked both tools and it appears that MagicPrefs does not support application-specific modifications. So I tried BetterTouchTool instead. It *almost* did what I wanted. The only thing that is missing is that it cannot remap my mouse click and insist that I add a "modifier key" (e.g. Shift, Ctrl, etc) to my right click in order to remap it.